# Why can't I drag window around by title bar?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

So I'm trying to have a window that I can drag around by the title bar. Since it's inside another frame I need to do this manually. This is what the code looks like for the mouse listener.

```
titleBar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            currentMouseEvent = e;
            dragging = true;
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            dragging = false;
            currentMouseEvent = null;
        }
    });
```

And this is the code for the update loop. (This is in a while loop on another thread)

```
if (dragging)
{
    try
    {
        setPosition(currentMouseEvent.getXOnScreen(), currentMouseEvent.getYOnScreen());
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        //do nothing
        Main.SoundSystem.fatalError();
    }
}
```

I know that the setPosition needs to be changed to track where the mouse is on the title bar, but I wanted to test this out. Problem is that it will move once, and then not again as I drag my mouse around. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't update `currentMouseEvent`, you keep moving the window to the location where the mouse was pressed.

You will need a `MouseMotionListener` to get new events during dragging.

Comment: How would I change the first code block to add that functionality?

Comment: @CPCookieMan: See the example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html). Basically you should add a `mouseMotionListener` to the titlebar, and a `mouseDragged` method that updates currentMouseEvent.

Comment: @CPCookieMan: Just keep `mouseReleased` as it is and you should be fine.